# Rounding issues when converting between arrays and tuples

Tags: python, numpy, set

I have a nested list of 2-element lists (lat/lon coordinates)

```
xlist = [[-75.555476, 42.121701],
[-75.552684, 42.121725],
[-75.55268, 42.122023],
[-75.55250199999999, 42.125071999999996],
[-75.552611, 42.131277] ... ]
```

that I want to convert into a set.  Before I do the conversion, however, I really want to round these values down to a lower precision so I can perform set operations on other similar lists and look for points common to both lists.

I can round with numpy,

```
x = np.round( xlist, decimals = 4 )
array([[-75.5555,  42.1217],
   [-75.5527,  42.1217],
   [-75.5527,  42.122 ],
   ..., 
   [-75.5552,  42.1086],
   [-75.5553,  42.1152],
   [-75.5555,  42.1217]])
```

but then the resulting object is a numpy array which I can't convert to a set

```
s = set( x )
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

I tried converting the array back into a tuple of tuples

```
 t = ( tuple( row ) for row in x )
```

but this does nasty things to the precision in the conversion

```
t.next()
(-75.555499999999995, 42.121699999999997)
```

I've also tried doing this in a single step, and had no luck

```
map( tuple, np.round( x, decimals =5 ) )
[(-75.555480000000003, 42.121699999999997),
(-75.552679999999995, 42.121720000000003),
(-75.552679999999995, 42.122019999999999),
(-75.552499999999995, 42.125070000000001)]
```

Is there something I'm missing about converting between tuples and arrays?  How can I get from  a list to a set that has its items rounded to lower precision?

Is it even advisable to use sets with float elements?

Comment: You're seeing the results of `repr` which displays as many digits as necessary to recreate the exact binary representation. It isn't possible to round any closer than that. If you use `str` instead the values will look nicer.

Comment: P.S. It has nothing to do with the conversion between tuples and arrays.

Comment: Which you can prove, thusly: `print (x[0][0])`

Comment: Aha, so it's just the formatting of the print statement!  Thanks guys, I feel dumb now...

Comment: P.P.S. I wouldn't generally suggest using `float`s in a set since the exact representation might be off between two of them, but if they're all rounded consistently you should be OK.

Comment: With set do you just want to get the unique rows in the array? There is an easier way using `np.unique` with some trickery.

Answer (score 1):

I think the core of your problem is that you can't create a set with a 2D list... try this:

```
xlist = [[-75.555476, 42.121701],
[-75.552684, 42.121725],
[-75.55268, 42.122023],
[-75.55250199999999, 42.125071999999996],
[-75.552611, 42.131277]]

x = []
for i in xlist:
    x.append( [round(i[0],4) , round(i[1],4)] )

s = map(set,x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You say you want precise decimal fractions and floating-point isn't doing it for you?

This is a job for `decimal.Decimal`!

```
>>> four_digits=decimal.Decimal('.0001')
>>> x = tuple(tuple(decimal.Decimal(x).quantize(four_digits) for x in sub) for sub in xlist)
>>> x
((Decimal('-75.5555'), Decimal('42.1217')), (Decimal('-75.5527'), Decimal('42.1217')),(Decimal('-75.5527'), Decimal('42.1220')), (Decimal('-75.5525'), Decimal('42.1251')), (Decimal('-75.5526'), Decimal('42.1313')))
>>> set(x)
set([(Decimal('-75.5525'), Decimal('42.1251')), (Decimal('-75.5526'), Decimal('42.1313')), (Decimal('-75.5527'), Decimal('42.1217')), (Decimal('-75.5555'), Decimal('42.1217')), (Decimal('-75.5527'), Decimal('42.1220'))])
```

You can convert back to floating-point later, if you wish, or you can keep them in `Decimal` until you print them or store them.